# Use of Pixel.getRatio() over dp

Tags: react-native

Is it same to declare the dimensions in following ways

1.

```
StyleSheet.create({  
      container: {  
        width: PixelRatio.get()*5   
     }  
    })
```

2.

```
StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {  
       width: 5
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify width/height in your style, this value is in `dp`, so `width: 5` is `5dp`.

When you multiple a value with the screen density (`PixelRatio.get() * 5` in your example), you get the value in pixels. You can also use the convenience method `PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize` which does exactly that.

Comment: so its the same, but multiplying dp with PixelRatio.get()  gives more accurate result in pixel.